# SetWindowsHookEx failing on beta2 x64

Tags: .net, pinvoke, 64-bit

Sigh,  I have some code from codeproject (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx) for hooking global keyboard and mouse events. Suddenly now when I installed beta 2 of visual studio 2010 and .net framework 4.0 i breaks at this code:

```
            hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(
                WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
                KeyboardHookProcedure,
                Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(
                Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]),
                0);
```

Oh, and I'm running  on a X64 machine. Anyone know a way around this? Not an easy fix I know..

Comment: Break = crash or NULL hook or ... ?

Comment: You're getting a compiler error on that code above? What is it?

Comment: not an error per se, hKeyboardHook is set to 0, and Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();  is also set to 0. Another user is getting a "Error code #87 (-2147467259) is being passed to Win32Exception, and it is failing with a "parameter incorrect" error there." But not me curiously :/

Answer (score 0):

Just did this for my project recently. It works like a charm ) 
I'm almost sure it's about 2nd and 3rd arguments.

1 wrap KeyboardHookProcedure() like this:

```
//declate delegate type:
public delegate int HookProc(int nCode, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

//use a class member of this type and inject your callback into
m_hookproc = new HookProc(HookCallbackProcedure);
```

2 for 3rd argument:

```
IntPtr hInstance = GetModuleHandle(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName);
```

3 be careful with Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() you have to use it strictly after the method you check for errors. ( [see this fxcop rule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182199%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

the whole picture then looks like this:

```
IntPtr hInstance = GetModuleHandle(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName);
IntPtr handle = SetWindowsHookEx(   WH_KEYBOARD_LL, m_hookproc, hInstance,  0);
if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
  int  error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
  //log the error or whatever
}
```

so that's all )

Answer (score 0):

Leave the Instance parameter as 0. Seems XP requires it, but win7 doesnt.

```
hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(
                WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
                KeyboardHookProcedure,
                0,
                0);
```